# How can I recieve multiple arrays in ajax, passed as JSON from the controller method in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to pass multiple arrays using JSON response from the controller method in laravel but I wanted to know how to fetch them in an ajax call. I'm a beginner so please correct if I'm wrong.

I'm already fetching events from calendar using ajax but now i want to fetch tasks as well.

Controller method:

```
$events = Event::all();
$tasks = Task::all();

return response()->json([  
       'events' => $events,
       'tasks' => $tasks
     ]);
```

Ajax:

```
  var events = [];
          var tasks = []; //step 2
          $.ajax({
            url:'events',
            type: "GET",
            datatype: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
              alert(data);
              $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(index, val){
                  //alert(data);
                  events.push({
                    id: val.id,
                    title: val.name,
                    start: val.start_date,
                    end: val.end_date,
                    start_time: val.start_time,
                    end_time: val.end_time,
                    location:val.location,
                    description: val.description,
                    calendar_type: val.calendar_type,
                    timezone: val.timezone,
                    allDay: val.isFullDay
                  });
              })
              //$this.$calendarObj.fullCalendar('renderEvents', events);
               generateCalendar(events);
            },
            error : function(error){
              console.log(error);
            }
          });
```

Comment: you can call data.events and data.tasks , make sure to check on developer tool

Comment: when I alert data.events or data.tasks, i get this [object Object] and nothing else & in the console.log i get this error: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Yes it is object ! View by console.log and loop as you need

Comment: okay I'm getting it in the console but what about this error:: 
Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  var events = [];
          var tasks = []; //step 2
          $.ajax({
            url:'events',
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
              alert(data);
              $.each(data.events, function(index, val){
                  //alert(data);
                  events.push({
                    id: val.id,
                    title: val.name,
                    start: val.start_date,
                    end: val.end_date,
                    start_time: val.start_time,
                    end_time: val.end_time,
                    location:val.location,
                    description: val.description,
                    calendar_type: val.calendar_type,
                    timezone: val.timezone,
                    allDay: val.isFullDay
                  });
              })
              //$this.$calendarObj.fullCalendar('renderEvents', events);
               generateCalendar(events);
            },
            error : function(error){
              console.log(error);
            }
          });
```

Comment: Thanks, Akash. I tried the same thing earlier and it worked.